# Problemas com menu-toggle AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação com `AngularJs` em cima de um template pronto com `bootstrap`. Até agora tudo está funcionando, mas notei que alguns eventos não funcionam, como é o caso do `menu-toggle`. Na pagina sem angular funciona perfeitamente, porém quando utilizo angular o mesmo não funciona.

[Esse](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) é o template que estou utilizando. As vezes tenho a impressão que o arquivo `.js` que não está sendo carregado.

Botão:

```
  <a class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  </a>
```

Trecho do arquivo `.js` que veio com o template:

```
$.AdminLTE.options = {
  //Add slimscroll to navbar menus
  //This requires you to load the slimscroll plugin
  //in every page before app.js
  navbarMenuSlimscroll: true,
  navbarMenuSlimscrollWidth: "3px", //The width of the scroll bar
  navbarMenuHeight: "200px", //The height of the inner menu
  //General animation speed for JS animated elements such as box collapse/expand and
  //sidebar treeview slide up/down. This options accepts an integer as milliseconds,
  //'fast', 'normal', or 'slow'
  animationSpeed: 500,
  //Sidebar push menu toggle button selector
  sidebarToggleSelector: "[data-toggle='offcanvas']",
  //Activate sidebar push menu
  sidebarPushMenu: true,
  ....
```

PushMenu:

```
$.AdminLTE.pushMenu = {
    activate: function (toggleBtn) {
      //Get the screen sizes
      var screenSizes = $.AdminLTE.options.screenSizes;

      //Enable sidebar toggle
      $(toggleBtn).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Enable sidebar push menu
        if ($(window).width() > (screenSizes.sm - 1)) {
          if ($("body").hasClass('sidebar-collapse')) {
            $("body").removeClass('sidebar-collapse').trigger('expanded.pushMenu');
          } else {
            $("body").addClass('sidebar-collapse').trigger('collapsed.pushMenu');
          }
        }
        //Handle sidebar push menu for small screens
        else {
          if ($("body").hasClass('sidebar-open')) {
            $("body").removeClass('sidebar-open').removeClass('sidebar-collapse').trigger('collapsed.pushMenu');
          } else {
            $("body").addClass('sidebar-open').trigger('expanded.pushMenu');
          }
        }
      });

      $(".content-wrapper").click(function () {
        //Enable hide menu when clicking on the content-wrapper on small screens
        if ($(window).width() <= (screenSizes.sm - 1) && $("body").hasClass("sidebar-open")) {
          $("body").removeClass('sidebar-open');
        }
      });

      //Enable expand on hover for sidebar mini
      if ($.AdminLTE.options.sidebarExpandOnHover
              || ($('body').hasClass('fixed')
                      && $('body').hasClass('sidebar-mini'))) {
        this.expandOnHover();
      }
    },
    expandOnHover: function () {
      var _this = this;
      var screenWidth = $.AdminLTE.options.screenSizes.sm - 1;
      //Expand sidebar on hover
      $('.main-sidebar').hover(function () {
        if ($('body').hasClass('sidebar-mini')
                && $("body").hasClass('sidebar-collapse')
                && $(window).width() > screenWidth) {
          _this.expand();
        }
      }, function () {
        if ($('body').hasClass('sidebar-mini')
                && $('body').hasClass('sidebar-expanded-on-hover')
                && $(window).width() > screenWidth) {
          _this.collapse();
        }
      });
    },
    expand: function () {
      $("body").removeClass('sidebar-collapse').addClass('sidebar-expanded-on-hover');
    },
    collapse: function () {
      if ($('body').hasClass('sidebar-expanded-on-hover')) {
        $('body').removeClass('sidebar-expanded-on-hover').addClass('sidebar-collapse');
      }
    }
  };
```

Qual poderia ser o problema? Será que é necessário fazer alguma alteração nesse arquivo `.js`?

OBS: Estou fazendo as importações dos arquivos no index.html e na ordem certa. Também não tenho nenhum erro no console quando aperto o botão.

Comment: Esse é um dos problemas ao se usar um template desse estilo.. ficamos muito amarrados ao template e qualquer mudança pode ser uma baita dor de cabeça =x Mas o que exatamente não funciona? Ele não abre o menu?

Comment: O menu já carrega aberto, o problema está quando clico no botão pra esconde-lo, dai não funciona.

Comment: @Techies qual versão do AdminLTE que vc tá usando?

Comment: @adelmo00 2.3.0, essa aqui: https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/documentation/index.html

Comment: @Techies vc importou o arquivo do jquery antes do app.js ? Tô usando esse mesmo template com angularjs e tá funcionando o toggle.

Comment: Sim, primeiro ta o jquery, depois bootstrap e por ultimo o app.js. Você fez alguma outra alteração?